# http connection works with IP address in Nginx but not with domain name

Tags: networking, http, nginx

I have a website setup using Nginx. If I try to connect through IP it works fine. But whenever I try to connect through domain name, I got connection reset error.

```
telnet mydomain 80
```

Works fine. But:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Gives the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 03 Apr 2016 05:59:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 181
Connection: close
```

Is there some Nginx configuration I have to do?

Comment: Are you accessing the website from windows machine? if yes how many machines will be used to access this?

Comment: No. It's Ubuntu.